# Why my ArrayList of HashMap type is giving wrong data after putting values in it?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm putting some data into `HashMap<Integer, String>` and then adding this hashMap into an `ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>>` but when I console the data after adding into array it always give the last added data to its size.

Here you can see logCat data which am I getting. [image]

Please check what am I doing wrong?

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>> imgMapList = new ArrayList<>();

for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { //runs 2 time

                        int inc = 0;
                        hashMap.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshotEvd : snapshot.child("evidence").getChildren()) { //runs 3 time
                            String claimedEvdImgURL = snapshotEvd.getValue(String.class);

                            hashMap.put(inc, claimedEvdImgURL);
                            inc = inc + 1;
                        }

                        imgMapList.add(hashMap);

                        Log.i(">>>", "hashMap:" +  hashMap);

                        Log.i(">>>", "imgMapList:" +  imgMapList);

                    }
```

Comment: You keep putting the same map into the list. Don't clear it, create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding same map reference every time in arraylist, create new HashMap inside loop. `hashMap.clear()` only clear data not reference.

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
   ...
}
```